# Airport Extreme as wireless bridge?

Tags: network, airport

I was hoping to use an old Airport Extreme as a wireless bridge. (At least I think that's the correct term.)

I.e.,

```
Modem →eth→ Asus 87U router →wifi→ Airport →eth→ Laptop
```

So far no joy. The Airport successfully connects to Asus over WiFi, but I'm not getting any internet from its ethernet LAN ports.

Under "Internet" it's set to DHCP. Working.

Under "Wireless" it's set to "Join a network." I also tried "Extend a network."

Any solutions?

**UPDATE**

After some fiddling (using "extend network", setting a static IP, etc.) it seems to be working – in that I am getting Internet from its Eth ports – but it's showing a flashing amber:

[image]

I clicked "Ignore" and now it's green.

Comment: When you say "no joy," what have you tired?  There's lists of  instructions at https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT20205, did you try anything here?  When you say  no  Internet from the ports, did you check to see if you got an IP address?